# Unparable Bluetooth module

Tags: hardware, bluetooth

I'm doing application in Android Studio that will scan for devices within reach of a phone. What it does exactly is not important. The problem is, that when I scan for devices, I'd get only the ones that aren't paired. Paired ones are stored in separate list and Android's discovery process automatically skips them. As far as I looked it seems I can't change that.

So I need Bluetooth module that won't be able to get paired with a phone, to be 100% sure the whole project will work correctly.

Is it possible to set a module (like HC-06) to make it unparable?

Can I buy a module like that somewhere? I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Omicron, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: I can't tell what your goal is here. Are you trying to make a fake bluetooth module? Something that looks like a bluetooth module but can't be paired?

Comment: I made my question a little more detailed. I just need a module that would be only discoverable

Comment: wouldn't that be literarly almost any cell phone and any blutooth device that requires a passcode for pairing?

Comment: Well, no. If you use passcode and pair a device, app doesn't work properly.

Comment: @Omicron - I don't understand what you're going for here. You're looking for unpaired bluetooth devices, so just don't pair the device. I don't understand how this is an issue.

Comment: The issue is that I know that pairing device would make project work incorrectly, but if I want to distribute the project there's possibility that users could pair their phone with the device and they wouldn't know what's the problem.

Comment: @Omicron you are not thinking clearly ... any bluetooth device would work ... if you are worried about accidental pairing, then disconnect the pairing button

Comment: How can I disconnect pairing ability of a phone?